# Equality of variance when comparing growth trajectories in two groups

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, growth-mixture-model

I am trying to compare growth trajectories of a variable in two groups. My question is simple: should I hold the variances of the slope and intercept factors equal across groups?

Answer (score 1):

It is advantageous to use a method that does not make as many assumptions, and in particular does not assume that you have correctly transformed Y.  Ordinal longitudinal models (semiparametric regression) satisfy this.  Three of the most common ways to handle intra-subject correlation in semiparametric models are (1) use a Markov process, (2) use a mixed effects model with subject-level random effects, and (3) use GEE with a univariate ordinal model.  The Markov approach is the most flexible and powerful in general.   Details are at https://hbiostat.org/proj/covid19 including extensive case studies.  Also see the longitudinal chapter [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr).

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing *average* trajectories across groups (i.e., growth-factor means), then you do not need to constrain growth-factor variances.

If your growth-factor indicators are latent, make sure your latent scales are linked across groups.  For example:

- If growth indicators are common factors, test feasibility of scalar-invariance constraints across groups

  - Ferrer, E., Balluerka, N., & Widaman, K. F. (2008). Factorial invariance and the specification of second-order latent growth models. *Methodology, 4*(1), 22-36. https://doi.org/10.1027/1614-2241.4.1.22
- If growth indicators are ordinal (requiring at least 4 categories), test the feasibility of threshold invariance across groups

  - Mehta, P. D., Neale, M. C., & Flay, B. R. (2004). Squeezing interval change from ordinal panel data: Latent growth curves with ordinal outcomes. *Psychological Methods, 9*(3), 301-333. https://doi.org/10.1037/1082-989X.9.3.301